# Mean value theorem for multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$ with $a>0$ a constant. Then, is the following true?
$$f(x,y+cz,z)-f(x,y,z)=c\int_{0}^{1}(\partial_{x}+z\partial_y)f(x,y+\theta z,z)d\theta.$$

It looks like the mean value theorem for multivariable function but I don't know why $\partial_x$ appears.

Comment: That looks quite wrong. The right-hand side should be something like $c z\int_{0}^{1}\partial_yf(x,y+\theta cz,z)d\theta$.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous

Comment: @SahanManodya Yes.

Comment: @MartinR I agree.